# Update-Database MVC automatic migrations - There is already an object named 'StationsArrangeds' in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

`Update-Database` command was giving this error:

> There is already an object named 'StationsArrangeds' in the database.

So I deleted this table and now I'm getting this exception while trying to update database.

> Using StartUp project 'MetroTrain'. Using NuGet project 'MetroTrain'.
>   Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied
>   to the target database.
>
> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error
>   occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner
>   exception for details.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.StationsArranged'.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)
>
>   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Reader>b__8()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1 executing, Action`1 executed)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>
>   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>
>   --- End of inner exception
>
>   Stack trace ---
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__a()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__9()
>   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>
>   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
>   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at MetroTrain.Models.StationsContext..ctor() in c:\Users\ghousia
>   pc\Dropbox\iMaq\MetroTrain\MetroTrain\Models\StationsContext.cs:line
>   22
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown >
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo.CreateInstance()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type
>   contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config,
>   DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration, DbContext usersContext)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration
>   configuration)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String
>   targetMigration, Boolean force)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command)
>
> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

I've gone through forums no solution found.

Answer (score 0):

Manually deleting tables in code first causes EF to lose track of your model changes.

You can reset code first migrations by deleting migration history table and re-enable migration.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly because your database Migration table ("__MigrationHistory") is not sync with your Migration
you can change your Database Name in default connection string and create new database.
after create new database compare it with existing Database menualy and sync "__MigrationHistory" from new database to existing for later Migrate